# Mask RCNN predicts only one type of class out of several classes

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have 8 classes in dataset of handwritten text and symbols. but it only predicts only one type of out of the 8 classes. I'm using *matterport* implementation.

```
class SymbolConfig(Config):

# Give the configuration a recognizable name
NAME = "symbols"

IMAGES_PER_GPU = 2

# Number of classes (including background)
NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 7  # Background + 

# Number of training steps per epoch
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 100

# Skip detections with < 90% confidence
DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE = 0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you also need to add the classes in the load_custom() function.

like:

```
self.add_class("datasetName", 1, "class1")
self.add_class("datasetName", 2, "class2")
......
self.add_class("datasetName", 8, "class8")
```